# How to toggle 'obtain DNS server address automatically' using command prompt?

Tags: networking, command-line, dns

The settings are located at: Network and Sharing Center > Wi-Fi > Properties > IPV4 > Properties

I need to regularly switch between 'obtain DNS server address automatically' and 'use the following DNS addresses'

How could I toggle this using command prompt?

Comment: A quick Google suggests you can look in the registry, but you can also use PowerShell...

Answer (score 4):

The cmd.exe version:

To set your DNS server:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 10.0.0.1
```

To add a second one:

```
netsh interface ip add dns "Local Area Connection" 10.0.0.2 index=2
```

To revert back to the DNS server(s) provided by DHCP:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

(Replace "Local Area Connection" with the name of your interface, if needed.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are talking about Windows 10...

In powershell to set the DNS:

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 12 -ServerAddresses ("10.0.0.1","10.0.0.2")
```

And to revert back to the ones configured by DHCP:

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 12 -ResetServerAddresses
```

You have to find out what InterfaceIndex you have to specify. List your adapters with the powershell cmdlet ...

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

… and choose which one is appropriate